# How to write multiple columns in a csv file according to "Lists of tuples" obtained during "for loop" iteration in python

Tags: python

With due respect to the previous responses, I am going to completely change my question. I am generating lists of tuples as below.

```
for i in range(5):

TotalDistance = 0   # particle i starts moving from 0
TotalTime = 0 # particle i starts moving at time 0
driftpoints =[(0,0)]
while TotalDistance < 5.0:
    time = random.uniform(0,1) # paritcle takes time to move to next position
    distance = random.uniform(0,1) # particle moves by distance.
    TotalTime = TotalTime + time
    TotalDistance = TotalDistance + distance
    position = (TotalTime, TotalDistance)
    driftpoints.append(position)
```

An example list for first iteration is given below.

```
[(0, 0), (0.21724544874575513, 0.754467286127031), (0.25007307998158623, 1.118356895500405), (0.7047856454945854, 1.4755146942363875), (1.3710776008226833, 2.16401542582095), (1.9942383846177156, 2.9751487045440026), (2.707031044871571, 3.9578284975759295), (3.3278895170648877, 4.831285527860187), (4.000180863917544, 5.218308572399064)]
```

If it was a single list, I can save in csv file in the following format.

```
Time,                Position,
0,                   0,
0.21724544874575513, 0.754467286127031, 
0.25007307998158623, 1.118356895500405,
0.7047856454945854,  1.4755146942363875,
1.3710776008226833,  2.16401542582095, 
1.9942383846177156,  2.9751487045440026,
2.707031044871571,   3.9578284975759295,
3.3278895170648877,  4.831285527860187, 
4.000180863917544,   5.218308572399064
```

But I have more iterations to come. And the problem I am facing is adding columns for next particles. How do I save 5 pairs of columns for each particles in a single csv file? remember that the length of the columns can differ significantly because of the random numbers taken as the time and distance.

Please forgive me and redirect me to the solution if this or similar question has been already answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I did not get any response on my question except the first one after which I edited my question and the response was deleted.

Any way, I got it the following way.

```
transposed = []
 __________________
[for i in range(5):]
[  all             ]
[      my          ]
[        previous  ]
[____________code__]


    transposed=transposed+zip(*driftpoints)
FinalFile=list(itertools.izip_longest(*transposed))
```

The first line after my previous code transposed the lists created in each iteration and added to make a long list of tuples that look like

```
transposed = [(0, t1, t2,...t5),(0, x1, x2,...x5), ... (0, t1, t2,...t8),(0,x1, x2,...x8)]
```

The last code then re-transposed the list created so that each iteration appear in the next set of columns. Unlike zip(*transposed), it is not limited to the shortest length of the columns.

Finally, write the FinalFile to csv file as

```
with open('file.csv','wb') as out:
    csv_out=csv.writer(out)
    for row in Finalfile:
        csv_out.writerow(row)
```